# GET filelists for each subfolders | Each filelist put in txt-file,which placed in folders that it describe and named like this folder

Tags: powershell, foreach, subdirectory, filelist, file-listing

---

## SOLVED

---

For each subfolder, that contains images *.jpg need to create textfile list of images names (whithout extensions). Textfiles should be named same as its directory

**For example you have same directory scheme:**

C:\scriptfolder\            - Parentfolder for filelist_script.ps1
C:\scriptfolder\subfolder1\ - contains some jpg-files 
C:\scriptfolder\subfolder2\ - contains some jpg-files 
C:\scriptfolder\subfolderN\ - contains some jpg-files

**Result of script work will be:**

C:\scriptfolder\subfolder1\subfolder1.txt
"subfolder1.txt" - List of all images(.jpg) in "subfolder1" 
C:\scriptfolder\subfolder2\subfolder2.txt 
"subfolder2.txt" - List of all images(.jpg) in "subfolder2"
C:\scriptfolder\subfolderN\subfolderN.txt
"subfolderN.txt" - LList of all images(.jpg) in "subfolderN"

---

**SOLUTION**:

```
$gl = Get-Location 
$folderlist = Get-ChildItem -path $gl\ -Recurse -Directory -Name  
foreach ($folder in $folderlist) {
    Get-ChildItem $gl\$folder\*.jpg -File | 
    Foreach-Object {$_.BaseName} |
    Out-file -path $gl\$folder\$folder.txt  -Force;
}
```

---

Using **"BaseName"** parametr excludes file-extensions from shown data.
Change it to **"Name"**, if you need to get files names whith extension.

Comment: It's unclear what your specific problem is - what parent directory? Your `Get-ChildItem` calls are independent of each other. To make `Get-ChildItem -Include` work without `-Recurse`, you must (unfortunately) pass `*`: `Get-ChildItem * -Include *.jpg`. Please add clarifications directly to your question. Generally, `Get-Help <cmdlet-name>` provides help; adding `-Detailed` includes parameter descriptions.

Comment: That was rather pretty

$gl = Get-Location 
$folderlist = Get-ChildItem -path $gl\ -Recurse. -Directory -Name  
foreach ($folder in $folderlist) {
    $gciFiles = Get-ChildItem $gl\$folder\*.jpg -File | 
    Foreach-Object {$_.BaseName} |
    Out-file -path $gl\$folder\$folder.txt  -Force;
}

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very well asked, it is hard to understand exactly what you are asking. By the looks of it you want to get a list of directories containing a single **_** and then every **.jpg** file inside those folders appending it to a text file. This is pretty simple:

```
$folder = "C:\Users\user\Documents"

foreach ($subfolder in (Get-childitem -Directory $folder\*test*)) {
    Get-Childitem $subfolder -Name -filter *.csv | Out-file pctrlst.txt -append
}
```

There are a few issues in your code:

```
$subfldr = Get-childitem -Name -Directory *_*
```

The usage of -Name here returns only the folder name, not the full path. If you are changed to that directory in PowerShell then it won't be an issue but there is no need for that flag.

```
$pctrlst = Get-childitem -Name -Include *.jpg
```

`-Include` needs to be changed to `-Filter`

```
$subfldr | ForEach-Object { $pctrlst | out-file pctrlst.txt }
```

Here you are piping the names of the folders (not the path just the name) to an object loop where you are simply running Out-File on the same variable which holds however many jpg files that are located in the current directory. You are just overwriting the same file with the same data multiple times here.

Comment: Thanks to all who answeres! 
Look guys my full task is getting filelists for all subfolders. And give it names same as the folder contains it.  EXAMPLE:
F:\\189\recieved\ - this folder contains script (conditionally named "MAIN FOLDER") 
F:\\189\recieved\subfolder1\
F:\\189\recieved\subfolder2\
Theese directories contains *.jpg files
As result of execution script i need to get filelists 
F:\\189\recieved\subfolder1\subfolder1.txt
F:\\189\recieved\subfolder2\subfolder2.txt
and so on... 
Im really sorry about my English. I hope you understand what I mean...